# Transform location matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, location, transform

I have a matrix of x, y, and z in csv file, where x and y are the physical locations of z values. The first column is the x location, the first row is the y location.

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6      
0  z values   
1    
2    
3    
4
```

I would like to build a matrix and or data frame of three columns, e.g.:

```
X  Y    Z  
0  0  6.7
0  1  9.0
```

and so on.

The purpose is to create a relief map or xyz plot of these data.

Any thoughts on cleaning this up?

```
raw <- as.data.frame(read.csv(choose.files(), header = FALSE))
raw <- raw[2:15, 2:29]
rownames(raw) <- 0:13
colnames(raw) <- 0:27
g <- transform(expand.grid(x=as.numeric(rownames(raw)), 
                           y=as.numeric(colnames(raw))), 
               z=unlist(raw))
```

The second line is to declare `raw` as only the `z` values.

Any thoughts on generalizing the second, third, and fourth lines?

Comment: What is the structure of your CSV file exactly ? Could you make it available online, or at least paste some lines ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
transform(expand.grid(x=as.numeric(rownames(df)), 
                      y=as.numeric(colnames(df))), 
                      z=unlist(df))
```

Test data (From @Roland)

```
set.seed(42)
m <- matrix(rnorm(25),ncol=5)
df <- as.data.frame(m)
rownames(df) <- colnames(df) <- 0:4

#    x y           z
# 01 0 0  1.37095845
# 02 1 0 -0.56469817
# 03 2 0  0.36312841
# 04 3 0  0.63286260
# 05 4 0  0.40426832
# 11 0 1 -0.10612452
# 12 1 1  1.51152200
# 13 2 1 -0.09465904
# 14 3 1  2.01842371
# 15 4 1 -0.06271410
# 21 0 2  1.30486965
# 22 1 2  2.28664539
# 23 2 2 -1.38886070
# 24 3 2 -0.27878877
# 25 4 2 -0.13332134
# 31 0 3  0.63595040
# 32 1 3 -0.28425292
# 33 2 3 -2.65645542
# 34 3 3 -2.44046693
# 35 4 3  1.32011335
# 41 0 4 -0.30663859
# 42 1 4 -1.78130843
# 43 2 4 -0.17191736
# 44 3 4  1.21467470
# 45 4 4  1.89519346
```

Comment: This is great! Any help with generalizing above...?